# Angular Material table not showing data, giving _columnCssClassName is not iterable error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular Material app that where I am trying to show all the customers that I get from an API call... My app compiles but in the browser console I keep getting this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
> columnDef._columnCssClassName is not iterable (cannot read property
> undefined) TypeError: columnDef._columnCssClassName is not iterable
> (cannot read property undefined)

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it has something to do how I'm feeding the data to table columns

I have created an interface called Customers with the following structure:

```
export interface Customers {
  _links: {
    first: {
      href: string;
    };
    last: {
      href: string;
    };
    next: {
      href: string;
    }
    self: {
      href: string;
    };
  };
  _embedded: {
    customers: [
      {
        id: string;
        internal_id: string;
        name: string;
        name2: string;
        address: string;
        address_post_nr: string;
        phone: string;
        email: string;
        gdpr: string,
        mailing: string,
        tags: string;
      }
    ]
  };
  page: number;
  page_count: number;
  page_size: number;
  total_items: number;
}
```

then I have created a component where I would like to show my customers in a table with these columns: Id, name, address, email, mailing, gdpr, tags

here is the component.ts file code:

```
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  displayedColumns: string [] = ['Id', 'name', 'address', 'email', 'mailing', 'gdpr', 'tags'];
  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Customers["_embedded"]>;

  private customerSubscription: Subscription;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  private dataArray: any;
  constructor(
    private customersServcice: CustomersService,
  )
  { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllCustomers();
  }

  getAllCustomers() {
    this.customerSubscription = this.customersServcice.getAllCustomersList().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('res: ', res);
        this.dataArray = res;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customers["_embedded"]>(this.dataArray);
        console.log('this.dataSource: ', this.dataSource);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.customerSubscription) {
      this.customerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the components html table code:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="crm-table mat-elevation-z0">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.address}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.email}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="mailing">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Mailing </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.mailing}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="gdpr">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> GDPR </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.gdpr}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="tags">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tags </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.tags}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
      <td mat-cell class="left-text"> + </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I do not see `_columnCssClassName` anywhere in the code you posted. Please [edit] your question to include the code that mentions this property.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the error if you can.

Comment: @GregBurghardt what is stacktrace of the error and how do I get it?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for debugging purpose?

Comment: The stack trace should be in the browser console, if you press F12.

Answer (score 1):

Suspect that the issue was the type for the `MatTableDataSource`.

```
public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Customers["_embedded"]>
```

From the attached `<mat-table>` element, believe that the type should be: `Customers["_embedded"]["customers"][0]`.

1. Change the type for `MatTableDataSource`.

```
public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Customers["_embedded"]["customers"][0]>;
```

2. Change the type for `MatTableDataSource` in the `Subscription` as well. Make sure the `dataArray` is an array of `Customers["_embedded"]["customers"][0]` type.

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customers["_embedded"]["customers"][0]>(this.dataArray);
```

3. Also, the `Id` should be lowercase in `displayedColumns`.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'email', 'mailing', 'gdpr', 'tags'];
```

---

Or I would suggest creating a `CustomerItem` interface.

```
export interface CustomerItem {
  id: string;
  internal_id: string;
  name: string;
  name2: string;
  address: string;
  address_post_nr: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  gdpr: string,
  mailing: string,
  tags: string;
}

export interface Customers {
  _links: {
    first: {
      href: string;
    };
    last: {
      href: string;
    };
    next: {
      href: string;
    }
    self: {
      href: string;
    };
  };
  _embedded: {
    customers: CustomerItem[]
  };
  page: number;
  page_count: number;
  page_size: number;
  total_items: number;
}
```

And change the `dataSource` type as:

```
public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<CustomerItem>;
```

Comment: So your answer is giving me the following error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: columnDef._columnCssClassName is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)
TypeError: columnDef._columnCssClassName is not iterable

Comment: Could there be a mistake in my HTML markup?

Comment: Not sure, will be great if you can reproduce error in StackBliz.

Comment: ill do my best to replicate it... will add it to the post then